# login method is throwing error while subscribing in login component.A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

Tags: angular

[image]

```
login(email: string, pass: string): Observable {
  const headers = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    })
  };
  const data = {
    email: email,
    password: pass
  };
  const model = 'username=' + data.email + '&password=' + data.password + '&grant_type=' + 'password';
  this.http.post(this.API_URL, model, headers).pipe(map(res => {
    return res;
  }), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Comment: You need to add `return` in front of `this.http`, but that setup looks weird anyway, seems your `body` should actually be `HttpParams`?

Comment: ... and please format your question so that the code is a code block and therefore is readable.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
login(email: string, pass: string): Observable {
 const headers = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  })
};
const data = {
  email: email,
  password: pass
 };
 const model = 'username=' + data.email + '&password=' + data.password + 
 '&grant_type=' + 'password';
 return this.http.post(this.API_URL, model, headers).pipe(map(res => {
   res.json();
 }), catchError(this.handleError)); 
}
```